# python unicode encode not showing readable text

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I got a list that looks like this:

```
myList = [u'\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0447', u'\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0447']
```

Then I did this:

```
for x in myList:
    print (x.encode('utf-8'))
```

so I got:

```
'\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd1\x87'
'\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd1\x87'
```

I tried many encoding, decoding standards. None of them helped me. How can I get readable text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strings are already unicode (they start with `u'`, the `\u....` parts are unicode codepoints which python converts to an unicode object for you), so you don't need to encode them (you only encode `str`).

You just need to print them:

```
myList = [u'\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0447', u'\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0447']
for x in myList:
    print(x)
```

You might need to specify the charset of your terminal with `export LC_ALL=utf-8` if you run into issues while printing `x`

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are a sequence of codepoints. Each code point is a fixed symbol. To covert it to bytes use encode and supply it with encoding (usually utf-8). To get symbols from bytes (i.e. file on a disk) you need to decode (you should know the encoding in advance).

Use `print ' '.join([str(i) for i in myList])`